# Upgraded to C# 10 .net 6 now getting Compile error when building Context.cs OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Currently getting build error after upgrading to Net 6

> Error CS8795  Partial method 'XXXX.OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. XXXX.Domain C:\Users\jbalman\Source\Repos\XXXX.ERM\XXXX.ERM\XXXX.Domain\XXXXDbContext.cs    2520    Active

Note: that XXXX was PII Info.

Visual Studio isn't showing me how this should be refactored and I can't seem to find any suggestion online when I search. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Visual studio 2022

Comment: You can check what have been changed in .net 6 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/breaking-changes?toc=/dotnet/core/compatibility/toc.json&bc=/dotnet/breadcrumb/toc.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using EF to generate a new context to compare to my original code.

As a result, I changed the following:

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

to:

```
void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

Which solved the error. I'm assuming this was because of an issue with the new C# version.

Comment: Had a similar case where I changed "private partial void OnModelCreatingPartial" to "partial void OnModelCreatingPartial" after transitioning to .NET 6 and C# 10. Exact reason is unknown, as I'm doing some project cleanup alongside other changes, but I wanted to share in case someone else gets the compiler error.